# Prism Xamarin GetCurrentPage is it possible

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Is it possible to get what the current page in the navigation stack is when using Prism for xamarin?

I have noticed there is the

```
 PageUtilities.GetCurrentPage(mainPage).
```

What is the usage of the above?

I was looking for something like navigationService.GetCurrentPage()

many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at [the code for PageUtilities](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Forms/Common/PageUtilities.cs) it looks like this method will do what you want, i.e. return the current page in the navigation stack. It looks like it handles the scenario where the current page is a MasterDetailPage, TabbedPage, CarouselPage or NavigationPage, and returns the correct page. I've tested it a little in my own app and it works as expected.

You can pass `Application.Current.MainPage` as the parameter to the method, like so:

```
var currentPage = PageUtilities.GetCurrentPage(Application.Current.MainPage);
```

Comment: Could you show me a little snippet of how you used the method inside your viewmodel? So suppose you have an app with 3 pages and 3 vms- VM1-VM2-VM3 etc.. and in vm3 you want to find out the current page what do you do?

Comment: @developer9969 see my edited answer, simply call the method wherever you need the current page, passing Application.Current.MainPage as the parameter.

Comment: thanks for your reply.Tried but MainPage is always null.Can you call this in the NavigatedTo method?

Comment: Correction is null only the first time round that It gets the correct page.Wonder where is the appropriate place to call this.

Comment: @developer9969 If I call it in the constructor or in the OnNavigatedTo method for the VM for the main page of my app, then MainPage is null (understandably) and the app crashes. But calling it in any other VM works fine.

Comment: First thank you for your time I did this main page.navigatedto navigateasync viewa in navigatedto (viewa)it crashes but 2nd time round  Ok so basically need to wait for main page to load and then can do it mmm